# How to hide full screen button of Mac OS window (in JavaFX)?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

Every window title bar of Mac OS has a full screen button at the top-right corner.Is there any way to hide this default full screen button of Mac OS in JavaFX?

[image]

Here is my code snippet:

```
    public static void  launchOkMessageBox(){
    pane  = new VBox();
    scene = new Scene(pane,150,60, Color.GHOSTWHITE);
    Label label  = new Label("Hello Word");
    Button okButton = new Button("Ok");

    pane.getChildren().add(label);
    pane.getChildren().add(okButton);
    pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    pane.setSpacing(10);


    messageBoxStage.setScene(scene);
    messageBoxStage.setResizable(false);
    messageBoxStage.sizeToScene();
    messageBoxStage.show();

    okButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {

            messageBoxStage.close();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At least for the [new dialog API](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/) it is sufficient have an owning `Window` with modality set to `APPLICATION_MODAL` (default):

```
Alert alert = new Alert();
alert.initOwner(mainStage);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to set the `StageStyle` to `StageStyle.UTILITY`

```
messageBoxStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
```

Comment: I think it should be messageBoxStage .initStyle and not messageBoxStage.initStage. Anyway it does not hide the fullscreen button, instead it hides minimise button.