# javafx: disable or hide full screen button on mac os application title bar

Tags: java, macos, cocoa, javafx, fullscreen

I cannot figure this one out.

What I want to do is somehow disable the full-screen button on the right side of the title bar of the main application window, that seems to be a feature of Mountain Lion (10.8)+. It has two arrows pointing outwards diagonally.

There are related answers to this problem if [the  window is a dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20880672/how-to-hide-full-screen-button-of-mac-os-window-in-javafx), and an [eclipse SWT-related solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834207/how-to-disable-fullscreen-button-in-mac-os-in-swt-java-app) here, but I need a solution to this problem if I have a single application primary-stage window, using javafx as the platform and netbeans 8 as the IDE.

I guess what I want is some way to access the cocoa API through javafx. Is this possible?

Comment: Simple answer: Avoid JavaFX.

Comment: Are you saying it's not possible?

Comment: I don't know anything about JavaFX, except that it does not do a very good job of being a GUI library. I would guess that it isn't possible.

Comment: so you offer advice about something of which you know nothing

Comment: you don't have to take it

Answer (score 2):

One way is to disable resizing completely:

```java
stage.setResizable(false);
```